# Select top 10 lowest values by group

Tags: r, database, dataframe, aggregate

I'm trying to get the top 10 lowest 'key_val' for each group = 'loc'

Table df2:

| Trends | loc | key_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| trend1 | Nigeria | 1 |
| trend1 | Nigeria | 1 |
| trend2 | Nigeria | 2 |
| trend2 | Nigeria | 2 |
| trend3 | France | 3 |
| trend4 | France | 4 |
| trend5 | France | 5 |
| trend6 | France | 6 |
| trend6 | France | 6 |

The table is not exhaustive but an example

I tried the following code:

```
data_new3 <- df2[order(df2$key_val, decreasing = FALSE), ]  
data_new3 <- data.table(data_new3, key = "loc")
data_new3 <- data_new3[ , tail(.SD, 10), by = loc]
data_new3
```

The result does not take into account the top 10 lowest values (key_val), but only the first or second.... I don't know how to solve this problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: Please don't use all-caps - it's generally regarded as shouting. And *always* show text as text, not as images. (It would also be worth showing some of your table context as text rather than as an image, too...)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df1 %>%
   slice_min(key_val, n = 10, by = loc)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the problem persists ..

Comment: Are you sure, that you know what you are asking for. some groups do only have 2 values therefore you cant get top lowest 10 (for example spain) in the provided data. You should through this <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: All my groups have at least 10 values, but I can't put my table here (105,245 total entries)

Comment: @LeilaZuccalli you have duplicates in key_val.  You may need `with_ties = FALSE`.  For the example you showed, `df1 %>%
   slice_min(key_val, n = 2, by = loc, with_ties = FALSE)`, I get 4 rows as output, 2 each for each loc